# Android mapview with setcontent()

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapactivity

Question about the map view. 
Ive got simple MapActivity, at first is just the list with details, each category leads you to mapview, but it not open new intent, instead change current activity by "setContentView".

Issue is when I show mapview, press back, which again change view by setcontentView and try to open another category with the same mapview, by showing different place and again is by setContentView... got error.

Why?

Comment: Can you post some of your class and error in Logcat?

Comment: there is no Logcat information, just some debug error with PhoneLayoutInflater

Comment: then, i think u should post some of your code so that others might help you out